# Store data from raspberry pi to MySQL server on remote desktop

Tags: python, mysql, database, remote-server

I am getting data from sensor to raspberry pi and was storing locally but I was having trouble with memory so I decided to store data on my laptop via LAN and I had mysql server setup on my laptop. I had looked over google to figure it out but couldn't find a proper solution. TIA

Comment: What language are you using? There are MySQL drivers for pretty much any language. I do something similar using Java and it's pretty easy.

Comment: @TheImpaler I am using python for this project

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you with Python. I added the "Python" tag to increase your chances those guys will spot this question.

Comment: @TheImpaler thank you